# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'document'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to enter `username` and `password` using python(2.7.10) and selenium and running into below error?how to fix it?

CODE:-

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/username/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get("http://website.com")
username = selenium.document.getElementById("Username")
password = selenium.document.getElementById("Password")

username.send_keys("username")
password.send_keys("password")

selenium.find_element_by_name("Login").click()
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>company Central Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/themes/bootstrap/theme.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/themes/bootstrap/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <style type="text/css">
        .vertical-align {
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .vertical-align > [class^="col-"],
        .vertical-align > [class*=" col-"] {
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -webkit-align-items: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            min-height: 24em;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -webkit-justify-content: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body onload="if (document.getElementById('username')) document.getElementById('username').focus()">
    <div class="container">


<div class="row vertical-align">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <form class="form" method="post" id="login-form" action="login"
          onsubmit="submitbutton = document.getElementById('login-submit'); submitbutton.value='Please wait...'; submitbutton.disabled=true; return true;">
      <h2 style="text-align: center;">Open Directory Login</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Open Directory Username" id="username" name="username" size="30" type="text" tabindex="1" accesskey="u" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Open Directory Password" id="password" name="password" size="30" type="password" tabindex="2" accesskey="p" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div style="text-align: right">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" accesskey="l" value="Login" tabindex="4" id="login-submit">
      </div>

      <input type="hidden" id="lt" name="lt" value="LT-1521352536r2EFE1A5DD6D459C1E4" />
      <input type="hidden" id="service" name="service" value="http:&#x2F;&#x2F;wifi-tech-web.company.com:8080&#x2F;login" />
      <input type="hidden" id="from" name="from" value="" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error:-

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'document'
```

Comment: Are you sure the IDs of `username` and `password` match in HTML code and your Python code?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj - even you change to `username` and `password` the error is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Selenium` is a module, and it doesn't have a `document` attribute, you need to use the `webdriver` to locate the element. `document.getElementById` is not a Python syntax anyway, its JavaScript. Try

```
username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
```

Keep in mind that the search is case sensitive, `username` is all in lowercase letters.

Comment: @Jeremyapple don't use `selenium`, use the `webdriver` (`driver`). Its the same error as before.

Comment: @Jeremyapple there is no element with `"Login"` name attribute in the html you posted. Make sure it really exists.